# Google trusted store not generating badge at checkout

Tags: onepage-checkout, googlestrustedstore

We switched OnePage Checkouts (Checkit Out!) and after switching GTS stopped working. Google has a way of previewing the GTS badge and we can see the badge on the site until we get to the checkout process. I don't see any JS error in the console. We are using the Turnkey GTS module.

[image: Not in Checkout]

This is in the OnePage Checkout - Note missing Badge in right corner

[image]

We have confirmed that the code is GTS code is there and there are no re-write conflicts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was alot easier then I thought

https://support.google.com/trustedstoresmerchant/answer/2609862?hl=en

Please note that the badge is designed to be hidden on secure (HTTPS) pages, with the exception of the order confirmation page, so as not to interfere with the customers’ checkout process.